# get_term_link() в Wordpress не видит ссылок на новые рубрики. В чём может быть дело?

Tags: wordpress

Делаю сайт на Wordpress 5.4.1. Сделал 4 рубрики, в них несколько записей. Вывел список рубрик на страницу через `get_categories()` и перебор полученных категорий. И всё работало, пока не создал в админке пятую категорию.

При этом `get_term_link((int)$term_taxonomy_id, 'category')` вместо ссылки на новый раздел, стал возвращать WP_Error. Для старых разделов всё ок.

> Recoverable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\wp-content\themes\nisarg\template\main-page.php on line 56

Посмотрел, что за ошибка:

> object(WP_Error)#4796 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["invalid_term"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(27) "Пустой элемент" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }

То есть, не существует элемента таксономмии. Эм... в смысле? У каждого раздела в админке есть и ярлык и даже описание. Подскажите пожалуйста, где и чего не хватает?

Если удалить любой раздел и снова создать, то он тоже становится причиной ошибки.

Код целиком:

```
$args = array(
    'parent' => 0,
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'exclude' => '', // ID рубрики, которую нужно исключить
    'number' => '0',
    'taxonomy' => 'category', // таксономия, для которой нужны изображения
    'pad_counts' => true
);
$categories = get_categories($args); // получаем все категории в виде массива
$images_raw = get_option('taxonomy_image_plugin'); // получаем все изображения в виде массива
$term_taxonomy_string = '';
foreach ($categories as $category) {    // перебираем массив полученных категорий
    $term_taxonomy_id = $category->term_taxonomy_id; // узнаем ID категории
    $term_taxonomy_name = $category->name;    // узнаем имя категории
    $term_taxonomy_link = get_term_link((int)$term_taxonomy_id, 'category');    // получаем ссылку на соответствующую рубрику
    $term_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($images_raw[$term_taxonomy_id]); //url картинки
    $term_taxonomy_string .= '<div class="service col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                                    <img src="' . $term_image_url . '" alt="' . $term_taxonomy_name . '">
                                    <a href="' . $term_taxonomy_link . '">' . $term_taxonomy_name . '</a>
                              </div>'; // формируем полученные данные и записываем в строку

}
echo $term_taxonomy_string;    // выводим сформированную ранее строку - рубрики с изображениями
```

Comment: Укажите в функции get_term_link вместо 'category' $category->taxonomy

Comment: Сделал. Ничего не изменилось. В $category->taxonomy хранится то же самое значение 'category' и ошибка в итоге та же.

Comment: Вместо `$category->term_taxonomy_id` напишите `$category->term_id`

Comment: Сработало. В таком варианте $term_taxonomy_link возращается успешно для всех категорий. Правда, у новых категорий пропадает $term_image_url. Поэтому $term_taxonomy_id для него я оставил вычисляться по старому ($category->term_taxonomy_id). Спасибо!